Feature Request: API for Posting Articles on LinkedIn via REST API
I'm working on an application that integrates with LinkedIn's API, aiming to streamline the content publishing workflow for LinkedIn members. Currently, the API supports posting text, images, and videos as user-generated content, but I couldn't find any documentation or endpoints for publishing long-form articles, similar to those created using LinkedIn's native article editor.
What I’ve Tried:

Reviewed the LinkedIn Content API documentation, which provides endpoints for sharing content but doesn't mention long-form articles.
Examined the LinkedIn Publishing API overview for additional details but found no mention of article publishing support.
Searched Stack Overflow and GitHub repositories for examples or workarounds but didn't find a solution.

My Question: Is there currently a LinkedIn API for creating or posting long-form articles programmatically? If not, does LinkedIn have plans to introduce such functionality in the future?
This feature would be incredibly valuable for applications aiming to enhance professional visibility by automating article publishing workflows. Additionally, if this functionality is in development or could be considered, what is the best channel for providing feedback or feature requests to the LinkedIn API team?
Use Case: Many marketing teams, prefer to post detailed articles on different social media platforms to engage their audience. Automating this process via the API would enable:

Enhanced content consistency and scheduling.
Integration with external content management systems.
Improved accessibility for users managing multiple platforms.

Thank you for your guidance and support!
